# Adding a "minimum" vertical space

Tags: spacing

Is there a way to add vertical space, but only if that much vertical space has not already been added? In other words, to say "put a minimum of *X* points of space here, and if some other command has already put in *X* or more points, do nothing"?

For example, I have a command which creates a blank line and then begins a paragraph, but it puts in too much space when used after a section heading, since the section heading already puts in its own space.

Comment: @vanden: Sure, the syntax would be appreciated. And in the real document, it's a multiple of \baselineskip - I just put in points for simplicity.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sounds like [\addvspace](http://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#g_t_005caddvspace) is the command that you are looking for. Simply use `\addvspace` instead of `\vspace` and you will get the *maximum* of the lengths instead of the *sum* of the lengths whenever you have multiple consecutive spaces.

If you are using the `titlesec` package to define your section headings, also have a look at the package option `largestsep`.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about that; thanks! (I've removed my hacky gets-kinda-close-but-not-really answer.)